# Question about the performance of normality tests SW, AD, LF

Tags: normality-assumption

I generated data from N(1,1) with size 10 this data is
(-0.1578085,  1.4050028,  2.7970624,  1.5112545,  1.4093379,  0.1866686, 1.2277188,  2.0653571, -2.1215896,  1.4512819)

its boxplot is

[image]

as you see there is skewness and outliers, however when I did Shapiro-Wilk test and AD test for normality they did not reject the null hypothesis, but when I did the Lilliefor test H0 is rejected
I know SW and AD are sensitive to the presence of outliers and skewness why that did not affect the decision and lead to rejecting H0

I want an explanation for the performance of these 3 tests in this sample

another question which best test for a small sample like 10 and 20, I read SW test not good with small samples while in other place read it powerful test for a small sample, so I confused about that

Answer (score 1):

You say you generated a normal data set of size $n = 10,$ happened to get an outlier, and now you're wondering why
a Shapiro-Wilk test does not reject your sample as being from a normal distribution. Because you *know* your ten observations
are from a normal population, you know S-W is giving you the correct verdict. True normal samples, even ones as small as $n = 10,$ do occasionally have outliers.

Three simulations in R should show that there is nothing
wrong or unusual about what you have observed.

(1) _Simulation showing a S-W test at the 5% level, rejects with
probability 5% as it should: $0.0501\pm 0.0014.$ You sample is one of the 95% of normal samples *not* rejected.

```
set.seed(2021)
pv = replicate(10^5, shapiro.test(rnorm(10))$p.val)
mean(pv <= 0.05)
[1] 0.05014        # aprx signif level near 5%
2*sd(pv <= 0.05)/sqrt(10^5)
[1] 0.001380238    # aprx 95% margin of simulation err
```

(2) *Simulation showing the power of the S-W test (at 5% level) detecting
exponential data.* The S-W test has power about $44\%\;\; (0.4424\pm 0.0031).$ The power is known to be low for
very small samples--even from populations markedly different
from normal. It can be problematic to rely on the S-W test to
distinguish whether or not a sample of size ten is from a normal population.

```
Set.seed(1234)
pv = replicate(10^5, shapiro.test(rexp(10))$p.val)
mean(pv <= 0.05)
[1] 0.4424
2*sd(pv <= 0.05)/sqrt(10^5)
[1] 0.00314124
```

(3) *Simulation showing frequency of boxplot outliers in normal samples of size* $n = 10.$ The result is that about 20% of
of normal samples of this size have at least one boxplot outlier. So, having an outlier is certainly not a criterion
for saying a small sample can't be from normal population.

```
set.seed(1227)
nr.out = replicate(10^5, 
               length(boxplot.stats(rnorm(10))$out))
mean(nr.out >= 1)
[1] 0.20372
```